# Getting inappropriate positions in GridView Drag and Drop when using Draggable Gridview in advancedrecyclerview library

Tags: android, gridview, draggable, android-gridview

I am using [android-advancedrecyclerview library](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview) to make a puzzle game and made drag and drop functionality in Grid View but it does not provide appropriate changed positions of Grids,

Issue is asked by me with full explanation here and added as open issue in library:

https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview/issues/269

Is there any other simple way to move grids by drag and drop them without using any library or is there any available other library that can provide convenient way to do it? If possible please give me solution without using any library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved now and they had updated their code and added new methods to support my suggested functionalities and it will be added in next release of [this](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview) library. And till now you can use this function by using this branch for library via JitPack and this functionality will be added soon in library.

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.h6ah4i:android-advancedrecyclerview:c9763e000fa8e80e6410f4a9d500e21b0e58a7e5'
}
```

You can see this in full explanation [Here](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview/issues/253) for this issue.