# RecyclerView Drag and Drop position not working android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have created a list using `RecyclerView` which has a drag and drop feature.List is as given below

List

List Item 1

List Item 2

List Item 3

If the user wants to drag list item 3 to position of list item 1, the list gets updated when the item 3 is near to list item 2. Hence the list gets updated as below

List

List Item 1

List Item 3

List Item 2

The Adapter class for the above scenerio:

```
public class VehicleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter {

    private VehicleInfoBean mVehicleInfoBean;
    private Context ctx;
    private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> expandedMap;
    private int indexOfSwipe;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final int row1 = 0, rowrest = 1;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ItemTouchHelper mItemTouchHelper;

    public VehicleAdapter(VehicleInfoBean vehicleInfoObj, Context ctx, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.bean = vehicleInfoObj;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(this);
        mItemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
        mItemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_odometer, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new OdometerViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        FCALog.d("adapter -- onBindViewHolder ---- " + position);

        VehicleInfoViewHolder vehicleInfoViewHolder = (VehicleInfoViewHolder) holder;
        vehicleInfoViewHolder.getIvDragItem().setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    mItemTouchHelper.startDrag(holder);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bean.getInfoBeanHashMap().size();

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        Collections.swap(bean.getSequence(), fromPosition, toPosition);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemDismiss(int position) {

    }


}
```

Let me know if faced similar issue with drag and drop position in `RecyclerView`.

Comment: got the solution for the above sol.the getItemViewType() was not returning an viewtype instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a same issue while implementing Drag and Drop in GridView i was using Android-advancedRecyclerView library,I also asked question about it on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051869/getting-inappropriate-positions-in-gridview-drag-and-drop-when-using-dragabble-g) and i also ask issue to author of library, and they have implemented that feature, See my question.

Although I found pretty useful blog [here](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.upplw33bh), there is no need to use any external library you can use RecyclerView's inner functionality, Maybe its helpful to you.